# issue with getting special day

Tags: javascript, function, date, datetime

i'm trying to write a function to get the the date after 5 days from a start day including just workingdays(Mon-Frid).
the problem i did not find a way to add just five working day from my array after my start day
the calculation should avoid Saturday and Sunday.

```js
var weekday = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
];
const date = new Date();
let day = date.getDay();

// let day = weekday[date.getDay()];
function getDayAfter5Days(startDate) {
  const date = new Date();
  let day = weekday[date.getDay()];
  var currentDate = startDate;
  if (day != "Saturday" && day != "Sunday") {
    after5Wday = date.getDay() + 5
  }
  console.log(after5Wday);
}
getDayAfter5Days(new Date())
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to rename the passed var but you are not using it `currentDate = startDate` does nothing

Comment: var currentDate = startDate should probably be var currentDate = startday

Comment: What is the actual expected output? A weekday like "Monday"? Or a date like 2022-02-03?

Comment: And actually, for all days except Saturday and Sunday you can just as 7 days, because for instance adding five workdays to a Monday will always result in a Monday again. For Saturday you add 6, and for Sunday you add 5

Comment: @derpirscher the expected output is a date like 2022-02-03

Comment: @derpirscher the most importat thing that i have to add five days to my start day what ever is the startday. for ex ; startday : 03-02-2022(Thursday) =>after adding 5 workingday the output is (10-02-2022) or starday is 05-02-2022(Saturday) => + 5 days (saturday and sunday would not be count) output 14-02-2022

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+day+not+sunday+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.